# Java: NullPointerException 2D array of objects even array is initialized and filled

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

In a method forest() I create a 2D array of objects then I fill it. I am sure that the array is filled because I can display the content of the array in class Forest in method forest() as well as in class Tree in method setTree() as shown below. Unfortunately, I can't get to this content by method showContentOfTree() or elsewhere. An error apears: NullPointerException

The question is why it happens and what I should change?

```
public class Forest extends JPanel {
    private LoadImage loadImage;
    private Tree[][] tree;

    public forest(){
        setLayout(null);
        loadImage = new LoadImage();
        loadImage.Image();
        Tree[][] tree = new Tree[16][16];
        for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++){
                tree[x][y] = new Tree();
                tree[x][y].setTree(loadImage.loadForest(x,y));
                System.out.println("Tree species " + tree[x][y].treeSpecies);
                //here System displays loaded treeSpecies successfully
            }
        }
        showContentOfTree();
    }
    public void showContentOfTree(){
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++){
            System.out.println("Tree species" + tree[x][y].treeSpecies);
                            //here System DOES NOT displays loaded treeSpecies:
                            //Error apears: java.lang.NullPointerException
                            //at Forest.showContentOfTree(Forest.java:31)
        }
    }
}

public class Tree{
    String treeSpecies;
    public void setTree(String treeSpecies){
        this.treeSpecies = treeSpecies;
        System.out.println("Tree species " + treeSpecies);
                //here System also displays loaded treeSpecies successfully
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Forest.showContentOfTree(Forest.java:31) 
at Forest.<init>(Forest.java:26) 
at Okno.<init>(Okno.java:19)
```

at Glowny.main(Glowny.java:10)

Comment: can you post a stack trace?

Answer (score 4):

You are [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your `tree` variable in your `forest` method.

```
public forest(){
        setLayout(null);
        loadImage = new LoadImage();
        loadImage.Image();
        tree = new Tree[16][16]; //<-- remove Tree[][]
```

Comment: you might say he cant see the `forest` for the `tree`s ...I kill me

Comment: +1, very good catch, this can almost count as an exam question :), my eyes just skimmed right over it